# Set up mysql replication delay

Tags: oracle, mysql

I have a mysql master-slave configuration in which the replication is instant.
I would like replication to be 60 or x number of minutes behind of the master.
How do I accomplish this?

I read that mysql 5.6 has such option but I couldn't get an info for my mysql version which is 5.5.

Cheers,
D

Answer (score 0):

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.2/pt-slave-delay.html

pt-slave-delay watches a slave and starts and stops its replication SQL thread as necessary to hold it at least as far behind the master as you request. In practice, it will typically cause the slave to lag between --delay and --delay"+"--interval behind the master.